# How to specify the following type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an interface in which we have a variable named `sortedTabs`. The variable `sortedTabs` is of type object which can have arbitrary many arrays in it but every array has the same type `tabsAn[]` but how would I specify that type? How would I tell TypeScript that I expect an object which holds an arbitrary number of arrays of type `tabsAn[]`?

```
export interface Initialization{
    sortedTabs: // how to specify the object described above?
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `{ [key: string]: tabsAn[] }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Would it still be an  object? Because I need the key in the object to specify which array should be used. How would that type look like in my interface? Edit: Thank you, I will try it!

Comment: It would look like `interface I { [key: string]: tabsAn[] }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways, the first being with an [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures):

```js
export interface Initialization {
    sortedTabs: { [key: string]: tabsAn[] }
}
```

The second being with the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), which is really just a wrapper around index types:

```js
export interface Initialization {
    sortedTabs: Record<string, tabsAn[]>
}
```